# Is there any drawback of using angular component in a cheap way

Tags: angular

The functionalities in angular component is no doubt valuable.

But I have some piece of html code which I just want to reuse, and reuse it a lot. So I am thinking of wrapping it into an angular component. Another benefit is to do `i18n` in this single component. It would be great as well.

Is there any drawback in doing this? Ex. performance, bundle size or other concerns, even potential cons.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you expect to reuse it only in angular applications?

Comment: Yes. and only in angular.

Comment: In this case I don't see any issues with this approach. My only  concern is that angular release breaking changes half a year or so, and I would recommend to use as less angular related stuff as possible (in reasonable manner of course). This will help you to use the component across bigger variety of version and make migration easier. 
Does this answer your question?

Comment: :) not really. But thanks.

Comment: Than seems I didn't get the question :) May be an update will be helpful?

Comment: Let's wait it out and see anyone else have more to say. I think you might be right. Not much a drawback after all.

Comment: @Hao You can use ng-template with ngTemplateOutlet Directive.

Answer (score 0):

You will have for sure the drawbacks of every Single Page Application. Your HTML will be rendered through JavaScript execution and then will be harder for search engines to understend what your application does and how to rank it. Plus that JavaScript files will take up some space and then the page will be a little slower to load up.